# Как занести в int[] массив ссылки на картинки из SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

**Вопрос:** каким методом можно занести в `int[]` массив ссылки на картинки из `SQLite`(а именно `R.drawable.img`) ?

Comment: Массив int[] ссылки??? может ты хотел сказать ID ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

айдишники ресурсов - это `int`, просто храни в айдишники SQLite в поле с числовым типом и доставай их. Но есть проблема. Айдишники меняются при компиляции. Это значит, что если ты выложишь приложение в магазин, юзер его скачает, запишет че то в базу, потом через 2 недели обновит приложение через тот же стор, то данные в базе уже не будут соответствовать реальным айдишникам ресурсов.

Это можно побороть так:
В БД храним в стрингах названия ресурсов. Чтобы узнать название ресурса, нужно сделать так:

```
Context ctx;
String resourceName = ctx.getResources().getResourceName(R.drawable.img)
```

Потом,  нам понадобилось добыть айди.
Тогда мы берем из базы имя ресурса и по нему восстанавливаем `id`

```
int resourceId = getDrawableResourceId(ctx, resourceName);
```

Метод для восстановления id по имени ресурса:

```
public static int getDrawableResourceId(final Context ctx, String drawableName) {
    final int lastPointIndex = drawableName.lastIndexOf(".");
    drawableName = lastPointIndex > 0 ? drawableName.substring(0, lastPointIndex) : drawableName;
    return getResourceId(ctx, "drawable", parseResourceName(drawableName));
}

public static int getResourceId(final Context context, final String resourceType, final String resourceName) {
    return context.getResources()
                  .getIdentifier(resourceName, resourceType, context.getPackageName());
  }
```

В этом методе вместо `drawable` можно подставлять и другие типы ресурсов.

Второй способ хоть и безопаснее первого, но он не устойчив к переименованию ресурсов

Comment: Есть бд с таблицей _year и столбцом в ней _foto integer. В нём находятся ссылки на картинки (а именно R.drawable.img). Как можно в int[] массив занести эти ссылки?

Comment: int id1 = ;
int id2 = ;
int d3 = ;
int[] arr = new int[] {id1, id2, id3}

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл очень короткий и работающий метод!!!
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", getPackageName());
где imageName это ссылка в бд- стринговое имя рисунка ( не R.drawable.img , а именно img!)

Comment: Но ведь я описал этот метод в своем ответе за 4 дня до того, как вы нашли его)

Comment: Спасибо,ваш ответ тоже помог. Но код почему-то не работал- parseResourceName-подчёркивался красным.Оказалась нужной всего одна строчка)